# box-shadow not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a div tag, on hover on that div and I want to apply `box-shadow`. In that `div` there is `image`, `label`, and `link button`. I just want to apply on div, not to each item that are inside of that div. But when I hover item of that `div`, `box-shadow` is applied to that item too.

Here is the code

```
<div class="itemshow">
    <asp:DataList ID="dlLatestItem" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataKeyField="Pro_Id">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="itemList">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgPro_Latest" runat="server" Width="200" Height="200" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="offer">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblOffer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Offer") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="cart">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCArt" runat="server">Add to Cart</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="ViewItem">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server">View Item</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="price">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Here is the code for `css`

```
.itemList {
    margin: 5px 18px 5px 0;
    border: 2px solid #5499c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.itemList :hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Comment: have you tired adding `px` to each `0` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `.itemList` and `:hover`

```
.itemList {
    margin: 5px 18px 5px 0;
    border: 2px solid #5499c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.itemList:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```